# If I run an empty iOS app, what is my phone doing?

Tags: ios

If I open up XCode, build an empty app that only displays a white screen, what is my iPhone doing while running that app. Is it just spinning endlessly?

Comment: This is the kind of question that the apple developer site is for. Ask there first, and then SO will be here for you if people there are unable to help you understand the on-phone application execution stack.

Comment: Ok I will do that, thanks Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's just waiting for user input.

On any iPhone (or any other modern GUI for that matter), there is something called the **UI THREAD**. That *thread* runs until the program exits and it's just coordinating all the UI and probably IO events. So, it's not just **spinning endlessly** but working along with the Operating System to support your application's interaction with the user.

In iOS, the **UI THREAD** is called **iOS Main Thread**. [Here's a blog post](http://blog.grio.com/2014/04/understanding-the-ios-main-thread.html) writing about it.